# implementing a generic interface with type constraints

Tags: c#, generics, c#-2.0, type-constraints

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# 2.0 CF project where I am implementing a generic interface, `IComparison`. The `IComparison.Compare` method may be called on to do any type of comparison that is valid to for the objects specified, so I don't want to put a type constraint on it.

```
public interface IComparison<EXPECTED_PARAM>
{
    Result Compare<RETURNED_PARAM>(RETURNED_PARAM returned);
}
```

The implementation, however, can be more specific. In this case, I'd like to say that the parameter given to `GreaterThan.Compare` can be compared to the `EXPECTED_PARAM` given in the constructor via `System.IComparable`.

```
public class GreaterThan<EXPECTED_PARAM> : IComparison<EXPECTED_PARAM>
{
    private EXPECTED_PARAM expected_;

    public GreaterThan(EXPECTED_PARAM expected)
    {
        expected_ = expected;
    }

    public Result Compare<RETURNED_PARAM>(RETURNED_PARAM returned) 
        where RETURNED_PARAM : IComparable< EXPECTED_PARAM >
    {
        return ((returned == null && expected_ == null) ||
                (returned != null && returned.CompareTo( expected_ ) > 0)) ?
               Result.Fail : Result.Pass;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the error:

```
error CS0460: Constraints for override and explicit interface implementation methods are inherited from the base method, so they cannot be specified directly
```

What do I need to do to get the ability to perform arbitrary comparisons of `EXPECTED_PARAM` objects with `RETURNED_PARAM` objects?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
    public interface IComparison<EXPECTED_PARAM, RETURNED_PARAM>
{
    Result Compare(RETURNED_PARAM returned);
}

public class GreaterThan<EXPECTED_PARAM, RETURNED_PARAM> : IComparison<EXPECTED_PARAM, RETURNED_PARAM> where RETURNED_PARAM : IComparable<EXPECTED_PARAM>
{
    private EXPECTED_PARAM expected_;      
    public GreaterThan(EXPECTED_PARAM expected)     
    {         expected_ = expected;     }      

    public Result Compare(RETURNED_PARAM returned)          
    {
        return ((returned == null && expected_ == null) || 
            (returned != null && returned.CompareTo( expected_ ) > 0)) ?                
            Result.Fail : Result.Pass;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably what I will have to do. The only thing I don't like is that I didn't have to know the `RETURNED_PARAM` type until `Compare` was called before. For this, I have to know both types at construction time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your inheritance hierarchy is the problem. `GreaterThan` inherits from `IComparison<EXPECTED_PARAM>`, which means you're telling the compiler that it implements `Compare<EXPECTED_PARAM>`, but you want it to implement `Compare<RETURNED_PARAM>` instead. You could drop the generic constraint on your interface:

```
public interface IComparison
{
    Result Compare<RETURNED_PARAM>(RETURNED_PARAM returned)
    where RETURNED_PARAM : IComparable;
}

public class GreaterThan<EXPECTED_PARAM>: IComparison
{
    private EXPECTED_PARAM expected_;

    public GreaterThan(EXPECTED_PARAM expected)
    {
        expected_ = expected;
    }

    public Result Compare<RETURNED_PARAM>(RETURNED_PARAM returned) 
        where RETURNED_PARAM : IComparable
    {
        return ((returned == null && expected_ == null) ||
                (returned != null && returned.CompareTo( expected_ ) > 0)) ?
               Result.Fail : Result.Pass;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remove the type constraint from the `IComparison` interface, then I get the `error CS0460: Constraints for override and explicit interface implementation methods are inherited from the base method, so they cannot be specified directly`. Also, I prefer the generic `IComparable<>` interfaces to avoid the boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @PaulH I just (re-)tested my example code, it compiles. Does yours look different from mine?

Comment: Yes, it compiles as posted, but you mentioned dropping the generic constraint from the `IComparison.Compare` interface. If I eliminate that `where RETURNED_PARAM : IComparable`, then it does not compile.